# jquery autocomplete when rendering item on select showing error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I did this code every thing is working when I am not rendering data but when I using .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem or ui-autocomplete renderItem when clicking on dropdown list there showing error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined.

```
$(function () {
    $("#search-text").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: SITEURL + 'activities/searchAll/' + request.term + "/" + $('#h_date').val(),
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                data: {
                    term: request.term,
                    dateRange: $('#h_date').val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#search-text').removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');
                    if (!data.length) {
                        var result = [
                            {
                                label: 'No Matches Found!',
                                value: response.term
                            }
                        ];
                        response(result);
                    }
                    else { 
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            var searchType = item.searchType;
                            if (searchType == 'DESTINATION' && item.destinationName !== undefined) {
                                return{
                                    label: item.destinationName,
                                    value: item.destinationId,
                                    destinationId: item.destinationId,
                                    type: item.searchType,
                                    parentId: item.parentId,
                                    destinationType: item.destinationType,
                                    destinationUrlName: item.destinationUrlName,
                                    searchType: item.searchType,
                                    img: SITEURL + 'assets/img/location.png',
                                    icon: SITEURL + 'assets/img/location.png',
                                    url: SITEURL + 'destination/' + item.destinationName + '/' + "d" + item.destinationId
                                }
                            } else if (searchType == 'ATTRACTION' && item.title !== undefined) {
                                return{
                                    label: item.title,
                                    value: item.seoId,
                                    type: item.seoType,
                                    img: item.thumbnailURL,
                                    icon: item.thumbnailURL,
                                    pageUrlName: item.pageUrlName,
                                    primaryDestinationName: item.primaryDestinationUrlName,
                                    primaryDestinationId: item.primaryDestinationId,
                                    attractionCity: item.attractionCity,
                                    attractionState: item.attractionState,
                                    pageTitle: item.pageTitle,
                                    searchType: item.searchType,
                                    img:item.thumbnailURL,
                                            // url: SITEURL + 'attraction/' + item.primaryDestinationUrlName + '/' + item.pageUrlName + '/' + "d" + item.destinationId + "-a" + item.seoId
                                            url: SITEURL + 'tours/' + item.primaryDestinationUrlName + '/' + item.pageUrlName + '/' + "d" + item.destinationId + "-a" + item.seoId
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (item.title !== undefined) {
                                    return{
                                        label: item.title,
                                        value: item.code,
                                        type: item.searchType,
                                        img: item.thumbnailURL,
                                        icon: item.thumbnailURL,
                                        productUrlName: item.productUrlName,
                                        primaryDestinationName: item.primaryDestinationName,
                                        primaryDestinationUrlName: item.primaryDestinationUrlName,
                                        primaryDestinationId: item.primaryDestinationId,
                                        productUrlName: item.productUrlName,
                                        searchType: item.searchType,
                                        price: item.price,
                                        url: SITEURL + 'tours/' + item.primaryDestinationUrlName + '/' + item.productUrlName + '/' + "d" + item.primaryDestinationId + "-p" + item.code
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }));
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                    $('#search-text').removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');
                    var msg = '';
                    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                        msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                        msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                        msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                        msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                        msg = 'Time out error.';
                    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                        msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                    } else {
                        msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                    }

                }

            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert(ui.item.label);
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            if (ui.item.url !== '') {
                window.open(ui.item.url, "_blank");
            }
            return false;
        }
    })
     .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        if (item.price !== undefined) {
            price = "Price INR " + Math.round(RATES*item.price);
        } else {
            price = "&nbsp;";
        }
        if(item.searchType=='DESTINATION'){
            return $("<li>")
                .data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item )
                .append("<div class='list_item_container'><i class='fa fa-map-marker' aria-hidden='true' style='float:left;padding-right:2px;'></i><label>" + item.label + "<br>" + price + "</label></span></div>")
                .appendTo(ul);
        }else{
        return $("<li>")
                .data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item )
                .append("<div class='list_item_container'><img src='" + item.img + "'style='float:left;padding-right:2px;'><span class='search-label'>" + item.label + "<br>" + price + "</span></div>")
                .appendTo(ul);
    }
    };


});
```

Comment: Then check that `item` is defined first.  maybe try `item==undefined ? "-" : item.label`.

Comment: Usually, methods with `_` underscore aren't supposed to be overwritten.